# Container template parameter std::map or std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-meta-programming, boost-multi-index

In one of my projects I'm using a tree implementation, where I used the container
`C=std::map<K,V>` to maintain a list of children for each tree node. Each tree node has a unique name key `K` being normally a `std::string`.

```
template<typename V, template<typename Key=std::string,typename Type=TreeNode<V>,typename ...> typename C>
class TreeNode {
    typedef C<std::string, Value> cont_type;    
    typedef V data_type;

    cont_type childs;
    data_type value;

    cont_type::iterator genericFind(const K& k) {
        // Something generic here!!! 
    }
}
```

This implementation worked quite well for me besides the fact, that std::map doesn't respects the order of insertion in the tree. For some applications I need to keep the order of insertion, but for other applications the need for fast information retrivial is more important.

Hence `C` needs to be either of type

```
std::vector<std::pair<K, V>> // keeping insertion order
```

or

```
std::map<K,V> // fast information retrivial
```

No I have a problem with the implementation of my `TreeNode` class, still using explicitly the interface of `std::map`. Especially, it uses the member functions `find`, `erase`, `insert` that needed to be replaced by something generic, where the implementation for the both container types is quite concrete.

For example `childs.find(key)` needs to be replaced by `find(childs.begin(), childs.end(), key)`, whenever I plugin the `std::vector` implementation.

Maybe there is another solution, that I'm not aware of. This might be maybe `boost::multi_index`, but I'm quite unsure about this.

What might be the easiest way to solve my issue?

Comment: Vectors can be incredibly fast due to prefetching. Don't just dismiss them as being "slow". I would suggest (just for science) you do also a vector implementation and measure the performance differences you get.

Comment: Something like this might help: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59999/42409

Comment: Since one is a sequence container, the other an associative container, expecting to find anything close to symmetry is going to be wishful. Regardless, if fast-retrieval is really on the menu, don't discount `unordered_map` for your associative container. Worth measuring. Were it not for your `erase` requirement, I would have suggested just keeping a vector of values *and* a map (kind of your choosing) mapping keys to vector indexes, but that `erase` throws that option in the deep end of the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create dedicated overload functions, and use them

```
template <typename Key, typename V>
auto my_find(std::map<Key, V>& m, const Key& key)
{
    return m.find(key);
}

template <typename Key, typename V>
auto my_find(std::vector<std::pair<Key, V>>& v, const Key& key)
{
    return std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const auto& p) {
        return p.first == key;
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me after some modifications. Many thanks. I had to do the same with insert, but I found a common approach for erase. Unfortunately I needed four find functions for const and non-const behavior.

Comment: @FrankSimon: I can reduced to 3 functions for the `find`: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38ab9aca2e7a262b).

Comment: Wow! I need some time to digest this. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Create generic wrappers for your desired container "choices" with the same interface:

```
template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class my_map_wrapper
{
private:
    std::map<TKey, TValue> _map;

public:
    // Same interface as 'my_vector_wrapper'.
    template <typename TEKey, typename TEValue>
    void emplace(TEKey&& key, TEValue&& value)
    {
        _map.emplace(std::make_pair(std::forward<TEKey>(key),
                                    std::forward<TEValue>(value)));
    }

    // ...
};


template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class my_vector_wrapper
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<TKey, TValue>> _vec;

public:
    // Same interface as 'my_map_wrapper'.
    template <typename TEKey, typename TEValue>
    void emplace(TEKey&& key, TEValue&& value)
    {
        _vec.emplace_back(std::forward<TEKey>(key),
                          std::forward<TEValue>(value));
    }

    // ...
};
```

Templatize your tree node class on the wrapper itself:

```
template <typename TWrapper>
class TreeNode
{
private:
    TWrapper _container;

public:
    // Use "uniform" container interface...
};
```

You can now define convenient type aliases to choose between containers in user code:

```
template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
using MapTreeNode = TreeNode<my_map_wrapper<TKey, TValue>>;

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
using VectorTreeNode = TreeNode<my_vector_wrapper<TKey, TValue>>;
```

Comment: Good point. But the second template parameter of my_map_wrapper should be not TValue, but rather TreeNode<...>. Now I'm lost again.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. The approach suggested by Jarod42 was more suitable for my kind of classes. Even though I think yours seems to be more general. But I'm just in need for this two specializations.